# LINQ query for an in-memory List takes seconds on ToList() call

Tags: c#, linq

The following LINQ query is slow even for an in-memory List. It takes seconds to execute.

I tried both List and IQueryable and it is slow for both.

Can you provide any advice why it is slow?

edit:

The list has 350,000 rows. The logic is converted from a stored procedure to cache table in a list and retrieve data from memory instead of hitting database multiple times.

```
var list = GetData().AsQueryable(); //GetData returns List<MDEntity>
var query = (from g in list join ux in list on new {
    Page = sPage, g.Property, Product = sProdAll, Section = (Guid?) null
  }
  equals new {
    ux.Page, ux.Property, ux.Product, Section = (Guid?) null
  }
  into ux_join from ux in ux_join.DefaultIfEmpty() join up in list on new {
    Page = sPage,
      g.Property,
      Section = (Guid?) null
  }
  equals new {
    up.Page,
      up.Property,
      Section = (Guid?) null
  }
  into up_join from up in up_join.DefaultIfEmpty() where(up.Product ?? string.Empty) == sProd || up.Product == sProdAlt where g.Section == (Guid?) null &&
  g.Page == sPage &&
  ((g.Product ?? string.Empty) == sProd || g.Product == sProdAlt || g.Product == sProdAll) orderby g.Property,
  g.Product,
  g.Language select new MDEntity {
    Property = g.Property,
      Product = (up.Page ?? string.Empty) == string.Empty ? Coalesce(up.Product, ux.Product, null, null) : Coalesce(up.Product, "SA", null, null),
      Language = Coalesce(up.Language, ux.Language, null, null),
      Value = Coalesce(up.Value, ux.Value, null, null)
  });
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: How many elements are in your list?

Comment: Either put it truely in memory with ToList(), or execute it in an stored procedure where you can better control the query

Comment: L2O can be slow if you end up joining large collections together. You can speed it up if that's your problem using this technique: https://github.com/mcintyre321/LinqToAnything/wiki/Using-LinqToAnything-to-index-a-large-collection-using-a-hashtable

Comment: What exactly is the goal of that query? Hard to tell but there's 2 self joins on that list, probably unnecessarily. I see a lot of questionable constructs being used, but it's hard to give a potential solution if we can't make out what it's doing.

Comment: @mcintyre321 as the list is big, I will try the indexing option. Thank you.

Comment: What is `Coalesce`?

Comment: If you really need that many joins maybe you should consider a different data structure, e.g. a linked list or classes that have references to their related objects.

Comment: @NetMage my custom function - implementation of the SQL server Coalesce

Comment: Are you sure the type of `list` is `List<MDEntity>`? If it is, why are you doing `select new MDEntity`?

Comment: I would suggest considering `public static T Coalesce<T>(params T[] vals)  => vals.FirstOrDefault(v => v != null);
` or better still, just doing `a ?? b` rather than pass two `null`s.

Comment: Why are you doing a `join` with `Section = (Guid?)null` on both sides - that codes does nothing...

Comment: How many items end up in `result`?

Answer (score 0):

The ToList() call is the point at which the actual query executes. So that big block of code you have above, is being lazily executed at the moment that you call ToList().

Given that I see you're able to use AsQueryable, I'm almost certain this is ultimately a database query under the covers. Although, I could be wrong.

Prior to the ToList() call, C# does NO SQL calls. So actually, it is NOT an in-memory operation.

That is a fairly sophisticated query, so I'm not surprised that it could take a few seconds for the database to complete the query and for C# to then return the resulting list.

Comment: He/she says "GetData returns List<MDEntity>"

Comment: @mcintyre321 If that is true, why have `select new MDEntity` ?